# A process in LISTENING state is sending packets?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

My TCPView shows that a process called `winrdlv3.exe` is in TCP `LISTENING` state while the count of its sent packets is keeping increasing (no received packets)? How can a process in `LISTENING` state send packets? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easily. After all, a process isn't in *LISTENING* state, one of it's sockets is, and this means that it waits for connections. Other his sockets can be in the same time in a *ESTABLISHED* state, and those are definitely sending packets.

Check out this socket transition diagram:

[image]